# Splitting DataAccess and Service Layer. Missing ConnectionStrings and References

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I am new to .net development and I am still facing some issues regarding the design of my solution. As mentioned in another question of mine, my entire solution is currently split into 3 projects:

1) DataAccessLayer - Implements an Entity Framework. All the entities are defined here. A DataAccessContext which is a subclass of dbContext is also defined here. The code of the DataAccessContext is as follows:

```
public class DataAccessContext : DbContext
{
    public DataAccessContext() : base("name=DataAccessContext")
    {
    }
```

2) ServiceLayer- Implements methods for the UI and Business layers to access the entities from the localdb server. This layer uses DataAcessLayer as reference.

3) BusinessLayer- Implements business logic. Uses ServiceLayer as reference.

There are two issues that I faced which I am not able to understand:

1) In the ServiceLayer, when using an instance of the DataAccessContext (from the DataAccessLayer), I am asked to install the EntityFramework package. Why is this necessary? Doesn't my reference (DataAccessLayer) have the necessary package?

2) I tried to write methods in the ServiceLayer that the BusinessLayer can call. The code looks like this:

```
using ModelDTO.Models;
using DataAccess.Models;

namespace DataAccessService
{
    public class Class1
    {
        DataAccessContext db = new DataAccessContext();

        public IQueryable<BooksDTO>GetAllBooks(){
            var books = from b in db.Books
                        select new BookDTO()
                        {
                            Id = b.Id,
                            Title = b.Title,
                            AuthorName = b.Author.Name
                         };
             return books;
         }
```

Here I am getting an error message that the connection string "DataAccessContext" is not defined in my application log. Once again, the connection string is present in the DataAcessLayer which is implementing the EntityFramework. So why do I need it in my ServiceLayer project?

If I have to put in the ConnectionString in my ServiceLayer, should I simply combine my DataAcessLayer and ServiceLayer together? What is the benefit of splitting them?

I am rushing to finish this project soon. So I hope someone can help me soon. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should probably merge your data layer and service layer together. The GetAllBooks method you have defined in your service layer belongs in the data layer. If that is representative of other methods in your service layer then there is probably not a lot of value in separating your data layer and service layer.

I generally create a service layer (sometimes aka application layer) so that it sits above the business layer and data layer. It essentially coordinates actions and requests between the ui and business/data layers. The dependencies between the layers are as follows:

- The ui has a reference to the service layer
- The service layer has references to the business and data layers
- The data layer has a reference to the business layer
- The business layer doesn't reference any other layer

HTH

Comment: I must admit that makes sense. Thank you Sir.. Is your ServiceLayer just a regular Class Library with regular classes or does it extend some special inbuilt class?

Comment: Yep, my service layer is normally just a regular class library with regular classes that roughly correspond to core functionality within the application.